# Change values from terminal

Tags: xetex

```
\renewcommand{\name}{student}
```

i am using printing the word name in my case.
i want to have a script print for me the same files with different names that i will feed it with an array.
since i have to print the document for my students.

i am running the following command through terminal:

```
xelatex popQuiz.tex '\def\name{{name}}'
```

but the student name is not changing to name.

please help me know why `xelatex popQuiz.tex '\def\ime{{name}}'` is not getting affected by name change thanks

exam consists of 5 pages, every page has a name field with as "student" and class name as "class"

on the preamble.tex file i have the following:

```
\newcommand{\name}{student}
\newcommand{\class}{class}
```

and connected 5 pages to these and on each page i am using \name and \class, which is printing "student" and "class"respectively
now on the popQuiz.tx file
i am  using \input to attach the preamble.tex file which has already set values after inputting that i am using

```
\renewcommand{\name}{}
\renewcommand{\class}{}
```

what should i put in {} inorder to feed it values from the command line, so that i can be able to make a script for it

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you make sure that `$name` is actually expanded (you are using it within single quotes)? Do you get any errors or does just nothing happen?

Comment: even when i am placing name as a word it is not taking the place of student name. need help in xelatex popQuiz.tex '\def\ime{{name}}' command from the terminal, the array is not a concern for me now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another workaround: If your file is called "test.tex" do the following:

```
xelatex '\def\ime{name}\input{test.tex}'
```

But pay attention: If you call your cs like one your document class or any package defines you will either get an error or your definition is overwritten, so choose a unique name.

Comment: this is working but but as i want it, this one is adding a new tag called \ime, instead of rewriting

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: Command \ime already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

Comment: @Hazo So you want to rewrite something?! What do you try to achieve? Could you please add an example to your question?

Comment: @Hazo just comment out the `newcommand{\ime}` stuff from your document and run again

Comment: @Hazo Just put `\ime` into your `\name`. It's as simple as this and you can also vary the cs name if `\ime` is already taken/clashes.

Comment: really sorry guys and thanks for the help, i dont know why i have \ime, it was a typing mistake, but i really appreciate your help